# Async await in MVVM XAML Applications

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await

I try to understand how should I receive initial data in my ViewModels with async/await pattern. Let's look at the code:

```
public interface IPeopleService
{
     Task<IEnumerable<Person> GetPeopleAsync();
}


public MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People{get;set;}

  public MainViewModel(IPeopleService peopleService)
  {
       LoadMyData(peopleService);
  }

    public async Task LoadMyData(IPeopleService peopleService)
    {
       try
       {
          People = await peopleService.GetPeopleAsync();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
         //log       
         //notify user    
       }
    }

}
```

There is a PeopleService which contains asynchronous method to People Data. It is injected with IOC (whatever). After that I invoke asynchronous operation LoadMyData (to prevent blocking UI, so no await keyword) and inside that method I invoke asynchronous operation from service catching all exceptions and notyfying user. What's wrong with this approach?

I read article from msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx and when I noticed creating a generic class for this kind of Tasks and changing all my properties to use that class as generic parameter, change XAML Bindings to receive a Property.Result property, I think it's crazy and creates a big mess in the project. Furthermore properties in ViewModel specifies that this property is asynchronous which in my opinion is bad design. What is the EASIEST way to solve my problem? Is my solution acceptable to keep everything simple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> After that I invoke asynchronous operation LoadMyData (to prevent blocking UI, so no await keyword) and inside that method I invoke asynchronous operation from service catching all exceptions and notyfying user. What's wrong with this approach?

Your UI is not blocked while loading the data. That's good. But asynchronous data loading brings up some questions: What does the UI show while the data is loading? How does the UI show errors to the user?

In your current code, the UI list is just empty while the data is loading. IMO there should be at the very least a "loading" kind of state so the user can distinguish between an empty result set and an operation still in progress. Also, your `notify user` code I assume is bringing up a dialog box or something - via code, not via data binding. IMO an error indicator is better than a modal dialog.

The purpose behind `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>` is that it acts as a data-bindable asynchronous operation. So you can use its properties to change to/from the "loading" and "error" states. This is why your bindings have to change to `.Result` - because you're binding to the *result* of the asynchronous operation. If you don't want to display a "loading" indicator and you don't want to display errors via data-binding, then yes, `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>` would be overkill.

It depends on how much you want to do data-binding. If you're happy with it all being in code, then that's fine:

```
public async Task LoadMyData(IPeopleService peopleService)
{
   try
   {
      ... // Hide people display
      ... // Show loading indicator
      People = await peopleService.GetPeopleAsync();
      ... // Show people display
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      ... // Show error indicator
   }
   finally
   {
      ... // Hide loading indicator
   }
}
```

Or, you can do it all with data binding, which makes your code simpler:

```
// (wrapped in NotifyTaskCompletion)
public async Task LoadMyData(IPeopleService peopleService)
{
    People = await peopleService.GetPeopleAsync();
}
```

I've done it both ways, but I lean towards `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>` if I have a project that does a lot of asynchronous operations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In every application I handle these situations with indicators which solves all situations while my data isn't loaded yet etc. In my opinion your approach is too complicated for simple process as is loading an async data. It introduces new convention. In simple cases with many usages  I think it's ok, but as it's generics, didn't you have problems with inherited types etc? I like to keep my ViewModels be simple, introducing generic type for every property I expose is not clean enough. Isn't it bad design to enforce properties to be async?

Comment: @Zbigniew: The generics have never been a problem for me; the result values are the same type whether synchronous or asynchronous, and data binding always uses reflection. I don't see a problem exposing properties of a generic type - in fact, your original solution does, too (`ObservableCollection<T>`). And the properties are not "async" - that's not possible - rather, you're (synchronously) binding to the *operation*, not its *result*.

Comment: Instead I should create generic of generic (NotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<T>> which in my opinion, assuming there are more than few properties is less readable. But it's my personal opinion. But wrapping it with NotifyTaskCompletion is enforcing it to be asynchronous, am I right?

Comment: I think the notion of "synchronous properties" vs "asynchronous properties" is not a helpful mental model. Rather, the difference is between binding to "data" and binding to an "operation".

Comment: I tried to use your approach, but don't know what is the way to manipulate this collection in my ViewModel. Code I presented above won't compile because of line:    People = await peopleService.GetPeopleAsync(). RHS should be wrapped in ObservableCollection constructor. How can I achieve that in your approach? I tried: var getPeople = _peopleService.GetPeopleAsync();
            var notifyTask = new NotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<People>>(getPeople); but that won't work, how can I "manipulate" that result after? Should I create a new collection and bind it to .Result in ViewModel?

Comment: Like this:
 var getPeople = _peolpeService.GetPeopleAsync();
            var task = new NotifyTaskCompletion<IEnumerable<People>>(getPeople);
  public ObservableCollection<Person> People{ get; set; }
  People= new ObservableCollection<Person>(task.Result);
But that will prevent me for binding it as Task.Result in my View. So how can I use your class and have a possibility to manipulate it after the task is completed?

Comment: You should be able to do `People = new NotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<People>>(async () => new ObservableCollection<People>(await peopleService.GetPeopleAsync()));`. (Though in [my code](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/NotifyTaskCompletion) I use static `NotifyTaskCompletion.Create` methods to avoid most of the angle brackets).

Comment: Dont forget, that in setter of People you can do: _people.Task.ContinueWith() to for example select first item of received collection in combobox or somewhere

Comment: @StephenCleary should that be NotifyTask.Create<IEnumerable<Foo>>(() => _FooService.GetDataAsync());  or NotifyTask.Create<IEnumerable<Foo>>(async () => await _FooService.GetDataAsync());    (note the async await inside create or not.

Comment: @juFo: [In this case, it can be either](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).